# Custom newman reports are not loaded to newman run

Tags: npm, npm-install, newman

I tried to install a custom report 'teamcity' and tried to use it during newman run, and eventhough the package is installed properly, it throws 'reporter could not be loaded' error.

Please find the below details:
[image: Terminal Screenshot]

Same issue happens when I created my own report locally and tried to use it. But the in-built reporters such as html, cli works fine. Is there an issue here or am I doing something wrong here? Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install newman-reporter-teamcity globally and run

```
$ npm install -g newman-reporter-teamcity
```

Run your collection again.

```
$ newman run APITesting.postman_collection.json -r teamcity
```

I had the same issue. This is resolved once I have installed globally.